# New Line Not Working When Making HTML Form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to make an html5 form using JavaScript.

```
newLine = document.createElement("br");
var optionsForm = document.createElement("form");
optionsForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
optionsForm.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");
var selectColor = document.createElement("select"); //input element, drop-down
selectColor.setAttribute('type',"select");
selectColor.setAttribute('name',"colorMenu");
selectColor.setAttribute('id',"colorMenuID");

// Populate drop-down menu
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Select Color:";
option.value = "selectColor";
selectColor.appendChild(option);

optionsForm.appendChild(selectColor);
optionsForm.appendChild(newLine);
```

However, when I make the new drop-down menu, it is on the same line as the old one.  Appending the newLine element does not appear to have any effect.

Comment: Can u see the <br> tag appearing in the resultant html code ? try firebug to check it

Comment: have you tried using \n? or nl2br (php for line break)

Comment: Don't you want to run `optionsForm.appendChild(newLine);` **before** `optionsForm.appendChild(selectColor);`?

Comment: newLine = document.createElement("\n"); caused "InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid characte" with Firebug.

Comment: I was not able to expand the html code that called the JavaScript function with Firebug.  However, I selected the page, right-clicked and selected  "View Selection Source".  I did not have the <br> tag between the drop-down menus.  I did have it after the last drop-down menu and before the submit button.

Comment: I put optionsForm.appendChild(newLine); after appending the drop-down menu so that the next drop down menu, or submit button, would be on the next line.  If I put it before and after, and had three drop-down menus followed by a submit button, the first two drop-down menus were on the same line, the third drop-down menu was on a new line and the submit button was on a new line.  If I just had two drop-down menus and the optionsForm.appendChild(newLine); before optionsForm.appendChild(selectColor);, I had the drop-down menus on separate lines but the submit button on the same line as the latter.

Comment: I looked at the DOM with Firebug and the <br> is only added as a child after the last drop-down select menu.  despite the fact that I call it to be added after every drop-down select menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

```
var menuElement = document.createElement("div");
label = document.createTextNode("Label: ");
menuElement .appendChild(label);
var selectMenu = document.createElement("select"); 
selectMenu.setAttribute('type',"select");
selectMenu.setAttribute('name',"menuName");
selectMenu.setAttribute('id',"menuID");
menuElement.appendChild(selectMenu);
```

Then I add some options then

```
menuElement.appendChild(newLine);
optionsForm.appendChild(menuElement);
```